# Is there any downside when adding 'async' keyword to functions?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

When I try to use async/await in .net my project, and finally found that almost all functions have async keyword, because when they await other async functions themself should be async.

For example, when I use functions in some async IO lib:

```
async Task Foo(){
    await file.ReadAsyc();
}
```

then functions that call Foo() should be async too.

```
async Task Bar() {
    await Foo();
}
```

eventually, I found a lot of functions have async keyword.

Is there any downside (performance hurt or other)?

Comment: I'm having difficulty coming up with a cogent answer to this vague question. Can you ask a more precise question?

Comment: What do you mean by downside?

Comment: depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at the MSDN definition of [`async`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) modifier:

> Use the async modifier to **specify that a method, lambda expression, or anonymous method is asynchronous.** If you use this modifier on a method or expression, it's referred to as an async method.

And they continue:

> The method runs synchronously until it reaches its first **await** expression, at which point the method is suspended until the awaited task is complete. In the meantime, control returns to the caller of the method, as the example in the next section shows.
>
> **If the method that the async keyword modifies doesn't contain an await expression or statement, the method executes synchronously.** A compiler warning alerts you to any async methods that don't contain await, because that situation might indicate an error.

The `async` keyword comes into play when combined with an `await`. It is a sign telling the compiler *"this method should compile as a state-machine, so the control can yield back to the caller and continue when the asynchronous operation is complete and resume the rest of the code as a continuation".*

If no `await` keyword is present in the method, it will simply run synchronously from beginning to end, but **the code for the state will be emitted** and that is an important factor.

Now, when an `async` method is awaited, there is a state machine that the compiler generates. This does have a cost, although the framework team made sure it has minimum effect on your codes performance. More so, behind the scenes there is the `SynchronizationContext` which flows when you `await` (unless explicitly stating not to) which is responsible for marshaling the continuation on back to the originating thread.

For more on the insides, especially performance-wise, see Async Performance: [*Understanding the Costs of Async and Await*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx)

Comment: So I can add 'async' freely to any function?

Comment: Yes. Though i dont see any logical reason to add it to method signatures for no reason. When you do that, the compiler emits a warning saying your async method isn't being awaited. More so, it may confuse fellow developers.

Comment: @Zach I don't see how this answer gives you the info you looked for. It's an explanation about what's async/await rather than talking about downsides of async keyword

Answer (score 4):

When a method is marked with `async` a state machine is generated in code. This state machine contains considerable amounts of code. This should not be an issue when you write "real" concurrent code because the benefits of using async and await should outweigh the cost of the extra code. However, marking each and every function in your library with async is pointless and will lead to code bloat. Besides, the compiler will generate a warning if an async method does not have an await.

So, yes, there is a "downside" to using async as extra code is generated for the state machine. But this should not be a reason to avoid using async and await if you are writing concurrent code.

For comparison here is the IL of an empty function.

Without async:

```
void F() { }
```

```
F:
IL_0000:  ret
```

With async:

```
async void F() { }
```

```
F:
IL_0000:  ldloca.s    00 
IL_0002:  ldarg.0     
IL_0003:  stfld       UserQuery+d__0.4__this
IL_0008:  ldloca.s    00 
IL_000A:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Create
IL_000F:  stfld       UserQuery+d__0.t__builder
IL_0014:  ldloca.s    00 
IL_0016:  ldc.i4.m1   
IL_0017:  stfld       UserQuery+d__0.1__state
IL_001C:  ldloca.s    00 
IL_001E:  ldfld       UserQuery+d__0.t__builder
IL_0023:  stloc.1     
IL_0024:  ldloca.s    01 
IL_0026:  ldloca.s    00 
IL_0028:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Start
IL_002D:  ret         

d__0.MoveNext:
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0001:  stloc.0     
IL_0002:  leave.s     IL_001B
IL_0004:  stloc.1     
IL_0005:  ldarg.0     
IL_0006:  ldc.i4.s    FE 
IL_0008:  stfld       UserQuery+d__0.1__state
IL_000D:  ldarg.0     
IL_000E:  ldflda      UserQuery+d__0.t__builder
IL_0013:  ldloc.1     
IL_0014:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.SetException
IL_0019:  leave.s     IL_002E
IL_001B:  ldarg.0     
IL_001C:  ldc.i4.s    FE 
IL_001E:  stfld       UserQuery+d__0.1__state
IL_0023:  ldarg.0     
IL_0024:  ldflda      UserQuery+d__0.t__builder
IL_0029:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.SetResult
IL_002E:  ret         

d__0.SetStateMachine:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldflda      UserQuery+d__0.t__builder
IL_0006:  ldarg.1     
IL_0007:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.SetStateMachine
IL_000C:  ret
```

The state machine also consumes a small amount of storage to keep track of the state but that should not matter.

Comment: BTW I believe that while low-level details are an argument to talk about the question, there're more high-level details that demonstrate that async programming and async/await shouldn't be blindly used, but understanding how multi-threading works and the implications of async code. But your answer adds value anyway, because it demonstrates the big difference in terms of compilation.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. Don't know why the IL is not optimized when no await is used.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any downside (performance hurt or other)?

In general, if you're using truly-asynchronous operations (usually I/O-bound), any performance degradation from async is made up by greater scalability and/or a more responsive UI. The most important key is: *optimize for performance only when you have proven through profiling that performance is a problem that you must solve*.

As others have noted, `async` does cause a state machine to be generated, which takes up memory and has a larger code size. The best resources for the performance impacts of this are Stephen Toub's [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx) and [Channel9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T).

Note that there is one "cheap" optimization that you can take:

```
async Task FooAsync() {
  await file.ReadAsync();
}
```

is the same as:

```
Task FooAsync() {
  return file.ReadAsync();
}
```

This is a nice trick to use when you're doing things like method overloading and don't want to add the `async` overhead multiple times. However, if you have other code in the method, then you'll probably want to just use `async` and `await`.

Answer (score 1):

The *downside* is code consuming these async pattern-based methods must be aware that they work asynchronously. That is, every method calling an async method must be turned into an async method too.

While async/await pattern simplifies asynhcronous programming because the code *looks like a synchronous one*, developers require an advanced knowledge about multi-threading to ensure that their code won't end up in deadlocks, synchronization issues and unexpected behaviors.

For example, code hosted by IIS and ASP.NET will require special expertize (ASP.NET async pages, async tasks...) because of IIS process model which behaves differently than a regular executable application on Windows.

Finally, threading synchronization in a multi-threading environment might have a performance penalty if we're talking about a simple client application (your application might have an useless thread synchronization overhead), but once the client application requires a lot of I/O and parallelization, async programming will work better, because you're going to take advantage of your multi-core CPU. And if we talk about GUI applications, async programming will be a good way of avoiding UI blocking while long running processes are executed.